# Decomposition of a prime number $p$ in a subfield of a cyclotomic number field of an odd prime order $l$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $l$ be an odd prime number and $\zeta$ be a primitive $l$-th  root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.
Let $A$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$.
$G$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z})^*$.
Hence $G$ is a cyclic group of order $l - 1$.
Let $f$ be a positive divisor of $l - 1$.
Let $e = (l - 1)/f$.
There exists a unique subgroup $G_f$ of $G$ whose order is $f$.
Let $K_f$ be the fixed subfield of $K$ by $G_f$.
Let $A_f$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K_f$.

Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p \neq l$.
Let $f'$ be the order of $p$ mod $l$.
Let $pA_f = P_1\cdots P_r$, where $P_1, \dots, P_r$ are distinct prime ideals of $A_f$.
Let $P_1A = Q_1\cdots Q_s$, where $Q_1, \dots, Q_s$ are distinct prime ideals of $A$.

My question: Is the following proposition true? If yes, how would you prove this?

**Proposition**

(1) $r = (l - 1)/\operatorname{lcm}(f, f')$.

(2) $s = f/\gcd(f, f')$.

Answer (score 3):

The decomposition group at $p$ in $G$ is generated by the residue class of $p$.  It a cyclic subgroup of the cylic group $G$ of order $f'$.

We have $Gal(K/K_f) = G_f$, and $Gal(K_f/\mathbb Q) = G/G_f$.

Then the general theory of how primes split shows that $r$ is the index in $G/G_f$ of the decomposition group at $p$, i.e. the index in $G/G_f$ of the subgroup generated by the image of $p$ in $G/G_f$, which by elementary cyclic group theory equals $(l-1)/lcm(f,f')$.

Similary, $s$ equals the index in $G_f$ of the subgroup generated by the decomposition group of $P_1$, which is the intersection with $G_f$ of the subgroup
of $G$ generated by the image of $p$.  Again, elementary cyclic group theory shows
then that $s = f/gcd(f,f')$.